# How to Bind DropDownList with a Select result of List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code to get the datasource to bind to a dropdownlist in asp.net:

```
var list = countryRegionList.Select(o => o.CountryCode).Distinct();
```

I wish to have the column bind to both text and value

```
ddlCountry_Billing.DataTextField = "CountryCode";
ddlCountry_Billing.DataValueField = "CountryCode";
```

However it gave me an error saying could not find this column. So how to fix this issue if the datasource is a select view of a List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = countryRegionList.Select(o => o.CountryCode).Distinct();
```

This will return a collection of just the `CountryCode` property, which I'm assuming is a string, therefore there is no *CountryCode* property on a string to bind to.

You want a [DistinctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs), or use an anonymous type in your projection:

```
var list = countryRegionList.Select(o => new { o.CountryCode }).Distinct();
```

Note that `new { o.CountryCode }` is shorthand for `new { CountryCode = o.CountryCode }`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), and bind it like this -

```
var list = countryRegionList.Select(o => new { o.CountryCode }).Distinct();
ddlCountry_Billing.DataSource = list;
ddlCountry_Billing.DataTextField = "CountryCode";
ddlCountry_Billing.DataValueField = "CountryCode";
ddlCountry_Billing.DataBind();
```

OR

```
var list = countryRegionList.Select(o => o.CountryCode).Distinct();
foreach(var item in list)
    ddlCountry_Billing.Items.Add(new ListItem(item, item));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `var list` is actually `IList<string>` now, not whatever object is in `countryRegionList`.

You need to either remove `.DataTextField = "CountryCode"` and `.DataValueField="CountryCode` setters or do the distinct filter based upon the `CountryCode` but still return the full object.

Answer (score 0):

> var list = countryRegionList.Select(o => o.CountryCode).Distinct();

Assuming CountryCode is a string, list is already an IEnumerable<string>

Just take two lines:

```
ddlCountry_Billing.DataSource = list;
ddlCountry_Billing.DataBind();
```

And call me in the morning...